# from time without end time

Tags: grammar, time-reference

I would like to appreciate all reviewers of our paper. We submitted our paper two times and I would point to reviewers of both submissions and revise. If I say `from the first submission` does it have the mentioned meaning?

> I appreciate all reviewers of our paper **from the first submission** for their time.

Answer (score 1):

No, that would not be correctly understood by most people, since it over-emphasises 'first'.

I think I would have written it as "I appreciate the time of all those who have reviewed our paper since its first submission."

Comment: I would leave out the apostrophe in "its".

Comment: I don't mean only reviewers of first submission. I mean reviewers of both submissions.

Comment: I have added "all" and "since" to correct the meaning. And changed my first paragraph entirely!

Comment: Thank you. How can I write the sentence if I want that the sentence starts with "I appreciate all anonymous reviewers of our paper"?

Comment: If I say any submissions,what is the appropriate preposition?
I appreciate all anonymous reviewers of our paper ? any submissions for their ...

Comment: Why do you think that is a better structure?